# Nested in-memory-web-api i.e. longer uri

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I'm trying to develop an application using in-memory-web-api, however, I'm not sure how to deal with longer URI patterns.

For example, I need to fetch some configuration data from the server using `/api/v1/configuration/manager` and `/api/v1/configuration/customer`. I've structured my dummy data as follows:

```
const v1 = [{
  configuration: {
    manager: [{...}, {...}, ...],
    customer: [{...}, {...}, ...]
  }
}];
```

But I 404 error. This is how I formed GET request:

```
public getManagerConfig() {
  return this.http.get<any[]>('/api/v1/configuration/manager');
}
```

The idea is to map as best as possible my API in angular during the development. How do I deal with this kind of nested data and URIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the module `angular-in-memory-web-api` has not been designed for such cases. As a bypass, try this:

1. Your `apiBase` should be `api`.
2. Items in your array `v1` should have property `id = 'configuration/*'`:

```ts
createDb() {
  const v1 = [
    {
      id: 'configuration/manager',
      data: [{...}, {...}, ...]
    },
    {
      id: 'configuration/customer',
      data: [{...}, {...}, ...]
    }
  ];

  return { v1 };
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is an ancient question, I totally forgot :D Yes, the `angular-in-memory-web-api` does not support such a configurations. There are alternative JS api libraries, but either they don't support this or are too complicated to test in short amount of time (at least for me). In the end I wrote my own test API backend as a simple python script that return JSON files placed on the filesystem.